How correctly make uv for individual assets
I’m trying to create some assets for a nuclear interior scene, and I’m not sure if I’m doing it correctly.
I was wondering if it’s better to UV unwrap each asset individually (perhaps in low-res tiles like 512px or 1k) or if it’s better to stack multiple assets on a single UV tile at 2k or 4k resolution.
As shown in this photo, I’ve grouped assets that could share the same UV space, but with different sizes. 
I’m also wondering if the goal is to have all UVs with the same pixel/cm density (for the same plane) and if all UVs should have the same size. Additionally, is it crucial to put each asset on its own individual UV tile?
I hope I’m understandable.

You should consider the purpose first and you should do that individually for each asset, each material and even each texture you plan to use.
UV maps don't have much to do with resolution, except for the gaps between UV islands that you don't want to make too small for low resolution textures so that they don't share same pixels when the islands are too close.
How you set up tiles, if you need to use UDIMs at all and what resolution textures you should use entirely depends on the context that you have not shared at all so I assume you are greatly underestimating the importance of it. Consider the context first. The UV maps need to fulfill their purpose - they need to make the texturing work. So the answers you are looking for can only make sense if you decide what you are making the UVs for and why. You may not care about UVs at all in some cases, in some cases you may care about the orientation of your UV islands, in some cases you might want some parts to have higher resolution than others, in some cases you may want the UVs to be laid out in a way that the textures can make sense in 2d editing software, in some cases you may want to have multiple UV maps for the same object, sometimes you may want some islands to overlap, sometimes you may want them randomized and flipped in various ways and so on and so on. There are probably hundreds if not more ways to use UV mapping. Each individual case depends on what you want to atchieve.
Consider not making UVs as a separate step but as part of making each individual shader.
